# Endless while loop problem with try/catch

Tags: java, exception

I have a while loop that is supposed to catch a non-int input and ask the user to re-enter an int. However it just endlessly loops the error message.
Does anyone have an idea why its not not allowing scanner input the second time through?

```
  while(!enteredInt)
  {
      try
      {
          locus = input.nextInt();
          enteredInt = true;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          //user didn't type an integer
          System.out.println("You didn't enter a valid number, re-enter point where you will build your city");
      }
  }
```

Comment: What is `input` in this context?

Comment: What kind of object is input? a Scanner?

Comment: Catching `Exception` is very bad, don't do it. It could be a `NullPointerException` but you would never know. It would also produce the results you are describing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you enter a token which is not a number, calling nextInt does not move the scanner beyond the token.  As a result, it's just reading the same token over and over.

Here's the documentation for nextInt: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29 (although the relevant behavior is actually described in the version which takes an argument, here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28int%29 )

So, to give you a quick example, let's assume that the input string is `"1 2 Foo"`.  I will add an X to show where the Scanner is currently positioned.  It starts out `"X1 2 Foo"`.  Then the first call to `input.nextInt()` happens. It returns 1 and now we're at `"1 X2 Foo"`.  Then the second call to `input.nextInt()` happens.  It returns 2 and now we're at `"1 2 XFoo"`.  Then the third call to `input.nextInt()` happens.  It doesn't return, but rather throws an InputMismatchException and it also doesn't advance the Scanner.  So we're still at `"1 2 XFoo"`.  So when we call it a fourth or fifth time, the same thing happens.

To solve this problem, an `input.next()` call will consume the next token, whatever it is.  After this call, in our example, we would be at `"1 2 FooX"`.

Note, however, that the call to `input.next()` can also still throw exceptions.  Specifically, it can throw IllegalStateException if the Scanner is closed (which shouldn't happen in your code) or NoSuchElementException if the Scanner has reached the end of input (which won't happen if you're reading in from the keyboard, as I assume that you are).  But just to be safe, you should either catch those errors and break out of the loop or not catch them and instead declare them as thrown by your method.

Comment: Thanks a-lot. One follow-up Q, what do you mean by a Scanner being closed?

Comment: @Adam: The class Scanner has a close() method which can be used to close the Scanner so that you can't read from it any more.  This method is handy because a Scanner can be opened on a number of different input sources (files, pipes, etc.).  When it's called, it will also automatically close its input source.  However, if you were to call input.close() and then call input.nextInt() or input.hasNext() it would throw an IllegalStateException.  This will only happen if input.close() has been called.  It will not happen just because the end of input is reached.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation:

> When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.

So the same(not integer) token will keep throwing the Exception.

You can use next() method to retrieve that token inside the catch.