# Eclipse asks for a return statement though I have one

Tags: java, int, return, try-catch, inputmismatchexception

```
protected int readInt(String prompt) {
    try {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        int i = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        return i;

    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Insert a number.");
    }
}
```

Hi! Eclipse gives me this error at the method readInt(): "This method must return a result of type int." and gives the example solutions "Add return statement" and "Change return type to void". I've tried to put the return i statement outside the try-and-catch loop, but when I do, the return statement can't find the variable i.

I've been struggeling with this for a while now, and can't seem to make it work... I would appreciate any help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code `i` is declared outside of the `try-catch` block so that the return statement won't have any scope issues. Also it is given the value -1, so if an exception occurs then the function returns -1 to the caller.

```
protected int readInt(String prompt) {
    int i=-1;
    System.out.print(prompt);  
    try { 
        i = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();    
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Insert a number.");
        keyboard.next();
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: @HannaMarlene After an InputMismatch `keyboard` should be moved to the next token. See the edited code. Hope it helps.

Comment: @HannaMarlene: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676345/endless-while-loop-problem-with-try-catch) is a better explanation for your looping problem.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what happens if an `InputMismatchException` occurs.

Your code will catch it, print `"Error: Insert a number."`. And then what? Your function is declared to return an int and it has a path in which it does not return anything.

You should either return a value that cannot be returned otherwise, and indicates an error, or rethrow the exception.

Answer (score 1):

After your catch block add a finally block with your return statement:

```
protected int readInt(String prompt) {
  int i = 0;
  try {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    i = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    //return i;

    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: Insert a number.");
    } finally{
        return i;

    }
```

}

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: There would still be a scope issue inside finally with the return statement. Place the declaration for `i` somewhere appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are consuming `InputMismatchException`, it will not know what to return in case the `InputMismatchException` is thrown. You can either `throw` some `Exception` or have some `return` in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

If a method having return type, JVM should expect for a return value after calling this method, In this case return is with only try {}. suppose any case its not executing all statements in try segment then there is no return type , thats why you got compiler error. You can either put return inside catch segment and try segment or outside of both try and catch